# Validate select form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have this html on my contact form:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="type">Type of website?</label>
     <div class="col-md-10 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i></span>
               <select class="form-control" id="type">
                  <option>Business</option>
                  <option>Company</option>
                  <option>Personal</option>
                  <option>Online Shopping</option>
                  <option>Other</option>
               </select>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

How can I validate and pass data of this field in email?

Currently I have this:

```
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>
      <div class="col-md-10 inputGroupContainer">
           <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i></span>
               <input  name="type" placeholder="eg. Business, Company, Personal, Online Shopping, etc." class="form-control"  type="text">
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And I validate and pass it like this:

```
$data = array(
        'type' => $request->type,
      );
```

but that's input field what I want is my first sample (select box), so I'm not sure how to do it!

thanks.

Comment: Please describe more clearly. It's difficult to understand what are you asking

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> **First Give THe Name To `Select` drop down fields, then after Simplest Way Is use in Validation Rules with the name of `select` input fields. that you give `required`**

## Example:

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="Business_Type">
    <option value="">Select Type</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="Company">Company</option>
    <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
    <option value="Online Shopping">Online Shopping</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

---

## Validation rules

```
// Validation rules somewhere...
$rules = [
    ...
    'Business_Type' => 'required',
    ...
];
```

Comment: It worked for me when I add default value 0
<option value="0">Select Type</option>

Answer (score 11):

This will work perfectly.

```
$rules = [
    'selType' => 'required|in:Business,Company,Personal,Online Shopping,Others'
];
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do it like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="type">Type of website?</label>
  <div class="col-md-10 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i></span>
      <select class="form-control" id="type" name="typeSelection">
        <option>--Select type--</option>
        <option>Business</option>
        <option>Company</option>
        <option>Personal</option>
        <option>Online Shopping</option>
        <option>Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the rules :

```
$rules = [
    'typeSelection' => 'required|not_in:0'
];
```

`not_in:0` to avoid submission of the first choice witch is `--Select type--` :)

And to pass infos to the validation just use `$request->all()` because it will use the field `name` in this case `typeSelection` no need for ctreating a new array !

Answer (score 3):

In **Laravel 8** i use this, i found out that if you change the value to an other value trough inspect element *'yes i know this sounds funky'* still can be inserted into the validator and pass. Here's the solution

**Select:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="Business_Type">
<option value="">Select Type</option>
<option value="Business">Business</option>
<option value="Company">Company</option>
<option value="Personal">Personal</option>
<option value="Online Shopping">Online Shopping</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option></select>
```

**Validator:**

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'Business_Type' => 'required|in:Business,Company,Personal,Online Shopping,Other'
]);
```

Just enter the values that the validator must pass, all other values will not pass

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate your select with `required` and for that you need to setup select like:

**Select into blade:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="selType">
    <option value="">Select Type</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="Company">Company</option>
    <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
    <option value="Online Shopping">Online Shopping</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

**Validation rules somewhere:**

```
$rules = [
    'selType' => 'required'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if the selected value is exist in your table's column you can check it like this example

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="Business_Type">
    <option value="">Select Type</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="Company">Company</option>
    <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
    <option value="Online Shopping">Online Shopping</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

for above selection

```
'Business_Type' => 'required|my_business ,type'
```

This will make sure the selected value exists for example in the my_business table on the type column.
***if you select the first option it will return the error***

```
The selected type is invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put Value in each option
The first one should be

> value=""

and the rest put the values of them like this

```
   <option value="">Select Type</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="Company">Company</option>
    <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
    <option value="Online Shopping">Online Shopping</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
```