# Too many if else statement Laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement

I have a query where user can have 3 option value where they can either just choose one on each option or 2 of either option of even 3 of the option. However, when creating the if else statement in the controller, the if else comes up until 7 statements. Any ideas how to reduce the if else statement.
each if else statement gives different input inside,
as an example

```
if (1 !="" && 2 =="" && 3==""){

}elseif(1 =="" && 2 !="" && 3==""){

}elseif(1 =="" && 2 =="" && 3!=""){

}elseif(1 !="" && 2 !="" && 3 ==""){

}elseif(1 !="" && 2 =="" && 3 !=""){

}elseif(1 =="" && 2 !="" && 3 !=""){

}elseif(1 !="" && 2 !="" && 3 !=""){

}else{}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validate select form in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58863070/5882307)

Comment: don't use this many `if else` use early return patten  which is  easy to understand https://dev.to/jpswade/return-early-12o5

Comment: can you show an example of what you are doing inside one of these blocks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested if statements instead of this , I think it may help you on this scenario

```
if(1 !=""){
    if(2 != ""){
        if(3 != ""){
            // all statements are true 
        }else {
            // 1 & 2 statements are true
        }
    }else {
        // only 1 is true 
    }
}else {
    // all statements is false 
}
```

**OR you can do also**

```
    if (1 != "") {
        if (2 != "") {
            if (3 != "") {
                // all statements are true
            }
        }
    } else {
        // all statements is false
    }
```

Comment: If `1` is empty and `2` or `3` is not empty, then it will go into your `else` block (all statements false) which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

you can use this. This is not small but it is easy to understand

```php
if (!empty(1) && empty(2)  && empty(3)){
 return '1';
}

if(empty(1)  && !empty(2) && empty(3)){
 return '2';
}

if(empty(1)  && empty(2) && !empty(3)){
    return '3';
}

if(!empty(1)  && !empty(2) && empty(3)){
    return '1 & 2';
}


if(!empty(1)  && empty(2) && !empty(3)){
    return '1 & 3';
}

if(empty(1)  && !empty(2) && !empty(3)){
    return '2 & 3';
}

if(!empty(1)  && !empty(2) && !empty(3)){
    return 'all empty';
}
```

here i used [return early patten](https://dev.to/jpswade/return-early-12o5) to simplify